# Video iFrame standards on social media with VideoJS, JWplayer, etc.. in HTML5 and Flash

Tags: iframe, html5-video, tumblr, jwplayer, video.js

I'm trying to get tumblr to accept video.js iframes. What are the requirements of Tumblr video posts using iFrames, why do they accept some iframes and reject others. Is there something needed in meta data like facebook video? Are there any specific examples of iFrame standards acceptable to the major social media platforms (Tumblr, pinterest, twitter)?

EDIT - my fault i fixed the videojs iframe but any tips on video iframes within popular social media with 3rd party players is appreciated.. HTML vs flash vs metatags

specifically regarding tumblr, it no longer plays back videos from the posting page with 3rd party iframes, only youtube... and there is no thumb generated. How can we generate a poster or a playable iframe on the post creation side of things?

Here is the iframe i'm pasting into tumblr:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://yourname.github.io/jwplayeriframe/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.6/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.6/video.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      #example_video_1 {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%; 
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="" height=""
      poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
      data-setup='{"techOrder": ["flash", "html5"]}'>
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
    <track kind="captions" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
    <track kind="subtitles" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
  </video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you having any issues with the JW Player at all in regards to this?

Comment: i fixed the issue- but i'm leaving this up here for a second to ask if you have any tips regarding iframes with JW 5 and 6.. how to negotiate facebook pinterest tumblr and whatever.. especially your input on the facebook thing might help as they switched up their metatags awhile ago.

Comment: Glad you got it. JW5 and 6 should work fine in iframes without issues.

Comment: From the recent Video playback issues to the tag page issues to their own HTML guide no longer being reliable to the completely rude message I received from support when I pointed out API issues, I don't know what's going on at Tumblr HQ anymore. I'm glad you were able to get the video to work. I'm going to have to look further into this because it won't even show video iFrames from places like Vimeo.

Comment: For reference, Tumblr had a wobble with video embeds a few days ago. Everything was being wrapped in two `iframe` elements. Not sure if this caused the OPs issue, but it has now been resolved.